# How to render iD editor-style streetmaps?

Tags: openstreetmap, javascript, web-mapping, d3, id-editor

Is there a simple way to render OSM data (let's start with just streets and names for a [single metro area](http://metro.teczno.com/)) client side as nodes and edges like the new [iD editor](http://www.openstreetmap.org/edit?editor=id)?

I'm comfortable with d3 but am having trouble seeing exactly how they're pulling it off.

Comment: Are you thinking of http://maps.cloudmade.com/editor or https://tiles.mapbox.com/newmap#3.00/0.00/0.00 or do you want to render locally on your own server?

Answer (score 2):

The Id editor is basically calling the OpenStreetMap API, and requesting the data in osm's xml format.

It basically makes a request like: `http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=xmin,ymin,xmax,yamx`

Once the data is received by the client, it is rendered using the  `connection.loadTiles` function in `id.js`. The deployment code is hard to read, but you should have a look at the source code, available here: https://github.com/systemed/iD/

Using Firebug, and the Javascript debugger, it is pretty easy to figure out what is happening.